# Javascript - Move forward overlapping intervals

Tags: javascript, range, intervals, overlap

Having this input:

```
[
 {key: 'a', start: 0, end: 100}, // 100ms of duration
 {key: 'b', start: 10, end: 30}, // 20ms of duration
 {key: 'c', start: 110, end: 200}, // 90ms of duration,
 {key: 'd', start: 300, end: 400},
]
```

I'd like this output:

```
 {key: 'a', start: 0, end: 100}, // 100ms of duration
 {key: 'b', start: 100, end: 120}, // still 20ms of duration
 {key: 'c', start: 120, end: 210}, // still 90ms of duration
 {key: 'd', start: 300, end: 400}, // no modifications
```

I need to fix only the overlapping intervals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the duration of the item (by subtracting its `start` property from its `end` property), set its `start` property to the last item's `end` property and set its `end` property to the duration plus its `start` property.

```js
const arr=[{key:"a",start:0,end:100},{key:"b",start:10,end:30},{key:"c",start:110,end:200},{key:"d",start:300,end:400}];

for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i].start < arr[i - 1].end) {
    const duration = arr[i].end - arr[i].start;
    arr[i].start = arr[i - 1].end;
    arr[i].end = arr[i].start + duration;
  }
}

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your output is an array of objects, you can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
const input = [
  { key: 'a', start: 0, end: 100 }, // 100ms of duration
  { key: 'b', start: 10, end: 30 }, // 20ms of duration
  { key: 'c', start: 110, end: 200 }, // 90ms of duration
  { key: 'd', start: 300, end: 400 },
];

const output = input.reduce(
  /**
   * @param outArray {Array<{ key: string, start: number, end: number }>} The accumulated array output by .reduce()
   * @param key {string} The key of the current item
   * @param start {number} The start time of the current item
   * @param end {number} The end time of the current item
   * @param idx {number} The current item's index
   */
  (outArray, { key, start, end }, idx) => {
    // nextStart =
    //   if we're on the first item, use 0
    //   if start is greater than the end time, just use start
    //   else the end time of the previous item
    const nextStart = Math.max(start, outArray[idx - 1]?.end ?? 0);

    // add the new item to the output
    outArray.push({
      key,
      start: nextStart,
      // add the previous end (aka, the current start) and the duration of the item
      end: nextStart + end - start,
    });
    
    // return our output array
    return outArray;
  }, 
  [] // initialize our output array as the empty array
);

console.log(output);
```

If you want to use the less readable, hax0r syntax that veteran JS programmers might use, you can do this with a one line `reduce()` callback.

```js
const input = [
  { key: 'a', start: 0, end: 100 }, // 100ms of duration
  { key: 'b', start: 10, end: 30 }, // 20ms of duration
  { key: 'c', start: 110, end: 200 }, // 90ms of duration
];

const output = input.reduce(
  // can be one line, but expanded for readability
  (outArray, { key, start, end }, idx) => [
    ...outArray, 
    { 
      key, 
      start: Math.max(start, outArray[idx - 1]?.end ?? 0), 
      end: Math.max(start, outArray[idx - 1]?.end ?? 0) + end - start 
    }
  ],
  []
);

console.log(output);
```

The first method runs *slightly* faster for long input arrays (I tested with 1200 entries) because the second method creates a new array on every iteration and recalculates `outArray[idx - 1]?.end ?? 0`.  This snippet takes about 16 seconds to run on my 4-year-old machine.

```js
const input = new Array(300).fill(0).flatMap((_, i) => {
  const keyBase = i * 4;
  i *= 400;

  return [
    { key: (keyBase).toString(36), start: i + 0, end: i + 100 }, // 100ms of duration
    { key: (keyBase + 1).toString(36), start: i + 10, end: i + 30 }, // 20ms of duration
    { key: (keyBase + 2).toString(36), start: i + 110, end: i + 200 }, // 90ms of duration
    { key: (keyBase + 3).toString(36), start: i + 300, end: i + 400 },
  ];
});

const method1 = () => input.reduce(
  (outArray, { key, start, end }, idx) => {
    const nextStart = Math.max(start, outArray[idx - 1]?.end ?? 0);
    
    outArray.push({
      key,
      start: nextStart,
      end: nextStart + end - start,
    });

    return outArray;
  },
  []
);

const method2 = () => input.reduce(
  (outArray, { key, start, end }, idx) => [
    ...outArray,
    {
      key,
      start: Math.max(start, outArray[idx - 1]?.end ?? 0),
      end: Math.max(start, outArray[idx - 1]?.end ?? 0) + end - start
    }
  ],
  []
);

const sum = (acc, x) => acc + x;
const avg = arr => arr.reduce(sum, 0) / arr.length;

const methods = ['Method1', 'Method2'];

const obs = new PerformanceObserver(items =>
  ['Method1', 'Method2'].forEach(m =>
    console.log(m, avg(items.getEntriesByName(m).map(e => e.duration)))
  ));

obs.observe({ type: 'measure', buffered: true });

for (let i = 0; i < 20000; i++) {
  methods.forEach((m, i) => {
    performance.mark(i);
    i === 0 ? method1() : method2();
    i === 0 ? performance.measure(m, i) : performance.measure(m, 0, i);
  });
}

setTimeout(() => obs.disconnect(), 0);
```